# Как убрать приставку map в Golang

Tags: golang

Как мне убрать приставку map и прочее в Golang. Мне нужно только Headers без скобок, двоеточий и структур, карт. Есть код:

package main

```
import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    netReserve(os.Args[1], os.Args[2])
}

func netReserve(url string, port string) {

    simpleHTTPRequest, s_err := http.Get(url) //port non-located
    if s_err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[Info] [Fatal] DNS="+url, "locked! /404/")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("[Info] %s [Headers]", simpleHTTPRequest.Header)
    }

    /* reserverHTTP = strings.Replace() - new method */ 

}
```

Результат:

```
[Info] map[X-Cloud-Trace-Context:[0dd99fdd03e4c13973b11d1652e65c18] Vary:[Accept-Encoding] Date:[Wed, 27 Sep
017 11:28:38 GMT] Alt-Svc:[quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"] Content-Type:[text/html; charset=utf-8]
trict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000; preload] Server:[Google Frontend] Cache-Control:[private]] [Headers]
```

Я убрал Extra string при помощи `%s`, осталось убрать map и прилежащие ей основы. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо напишите свою функцию, которая будет создавать вам строку в нужном формате, либо оберните тип `net/http.Header` в свой собственный тип и напишите для него метод `String() string`. Грубый вариант с функцией:

```
func f(h http.Header) string {
    s := ""
    for k, v := range h {
        s += k + ": " + v[0] + ", "
    }
    return s
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/GWwPfwP01J.